# Cannot get CSS Drop-Down above Flash File

Tags: javascript, css, flash, dhtml

I have searched everything and tried every method I can get my hands on and cannot get my CSS drop-down menus to display above my Flash file.

You can go to: http://beta.riverlifefellowship.com and username is 'riverlife' and password is 'flow' (without the quotes on both).

I am using swfObject and have the `<param name="flashvars" value="wmode=opaque"/>` set. The div around the drop down is absolute position with z-index of 9999 and the div around the flash file is relative position with z-index of -1

Any suggestions of things to try is greatly appreciated!

[Note: It is working in all browsers on Mac OS but no browsers on Windows OS]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the wmode property on the Flash to transparent - that usually works

EDIT:
You are using `<object>` to embed the .swf - which is one way, but `<embed>` will work across more browsers and will actually solve the problem for the most part, combined with the wmode you already have set. Adobe Dreamweaver has a nice way of creating some javascript that handles the choice of  or `<object>` based on the browser. But without that your code should basically look like this. (This is tested in Firebug and worked)

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" 
    codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0" width="980" height="250">
    <param name="movie" value="/files/themes/RiverLife-Oct09/media/header_ssp2.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
    <embed src="/files/themes/RiverLife-Oct09/media/header_ssp2.swf" quality="high" wmode="opaque" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="980" height="250"></embed>     
    </object>
```

Comment: You do that in the HTML, its not part of the swf

Comment: I like your answer, and you beat me to it by about 13 seconds! hehe

Comment: I have the wmode="opaque" and still no luck. I tried transparent and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you actually *need* the transparency (i.e., you flash movie has a transparent background), the best choice is to use `opaque` for the `wmode` which will have better performance than `transparent`.  Only `wmode="window"` (which is the default) prevents the browser from drawing on top of the flash.

http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=e5141

> This mode is the one that confused me
>   due to this wording: "Opaque mode
>   makes the movie hide everything behind
>   it on the page. Additionally, opaque
>   mode moves elements behind Flash
>   movies (for example, with dynamic
>   HTML) to prevent them from showing
>   through." Truth is, since by using
>   wmode="opaque", you've placed the
>   Flash Player directly onto the page,
>   it can now accept placement and
>   positioning like any other element.
>   Unless your viewer is not using a
>   compliant browser (list to follow),
>   the z-index will be respected and
>   rendered. So yes, you can move
>   elements behind Flash movies to
>   prevent them from showing through, but
>   you can just as easily move the
>   elements in front of the Flash movies
>   to prevent the Flash from showing
>   through.

Answer (score 2):

Did you set the wmode to transparent?

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your drop down menu will work with `position: absolute`.

Edit:
I got a similair case where I also got a dropdown menu at the top and a flash object beneath it. In my case the menu has `position: absolute` and the flash object `wmode="opaque"`.
Maybe it's also worth mentioning that the menu is in a container div with `overflow: auto` and the flash object as well. This works for me.

Ok let's write this down..

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="menu"></div>
</div>

<div id="flashContainer">
    <object id=flash"></object>
</div>




#header
{
    overflow: auto;
}
#header #menu
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 40px;
}
#flashContainer
{
    overflow: auto;
}
#flash
{
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can look at my page\CSS and tell me where I need that? I have it on the out-most container for the menu and also on the drop-downs themselves. What am I missing?